# How to use require to import a file whose filename is not in English in Racket?

Tags: racket

I am trying to use Racket to "require" a file whose name is in Chinese. The compiler gives an error that `test.rkt:2:3: require: bad module-path string at: "./lib/算数.rkt" in: (require "./lib/算数.rkt") #(13 14)`, but it does work when I rename `算数.rkt` into `math.rkt`. So I am sure that the error occurs because the filename is not in English. Any method I can use to solve the problem?
[image]

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate this, and while I didn't dig deep into the documentation to see if there's some listed restriction about what codepoints can be in a module path, I did find a workaround:

```lisp
(require (file "./lib/算数.rkt"))
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._file%29%29) for `(file ...)`:

> Similar to the plain `rel-string` case, but `string` is a path—possibly absolute—using the current platform’s path conventions and `expand-user-path`.

[Other documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-paths.html) says

> This form is not portable, and it should *not* be used when a plain, portable `rel-string` suffices.

Since the normal way doesn't suffice, I guess this is one of the situations where it's okay to use.